# Distributing with Titanum and xCode - this kind of archive cannot be signed

Tags: ios, app-store, titanium, google-play

I have made an app with Titanium Studio, and now it's time for distributing with PlayStore and AppStore. It's already out on PlayStore, which was the easy part - but apple is very tricky to get through for me.

I've created an iTunes connect app for the archive.

I've archived the app using Distribute -> IOS Appstore.

Now, when I press the validate button in xCode, logging using my apple ID, selecting the 'app' I created on iTunes Connect, it says next to Identity:

`"This kind of archive cannot be signed"`

And when I click NEXT, I get this error:

```
"The archive is invalid. You must specify a path to the archive"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go the the iphone native project inside your project directory, open it with XCode and try publishing from there.

Comment: So I need to archive the iPhone-only version of the project??

Comment: do you mean iphone only vs universal (iphone + ipad ) ? 
if that was what u meant, you can archive an iphone only or a universal application. both will be possible.

Comment: okay, then I don't understand what the solution to my problem is - could you explain a little further? - sorry